React component with "as" property that points to another component and inherits it's properties too
I want to create a MyComponent with an "as" property which allows it to inherit the properties of the as component, such that I can get TypeScript typings.
e.g.
Usage with HTML elements:
<MyComponent 
  as="label" 
  htmlFor="caption" /* this should autocomplete from label */
  asdf="" /* this should give error */
  className="test"
>
  Test
</MyComponent>

With React components:
<MyComponent 
  as={MyGrid} 
  rows={4}  /* this should autocomplete from MyGrid */ 
  asdf="" /* this should give error */

>
  Test
</MyComponent>

I have this so far which works as a component, but unfortunately it doesn't inherit the types.
import { useRef, forwardRef } from "react";
import type {
  PropsWithChildren,
  ElementType,
  ComponentProps,
  ForwardedRef,
  ReactElement,
} from "react";


type MyProps<T extends ElementType> = 
  ComponentProps<T> &
  PropsWithChildren & 
  { as?: T };

function _MyComponent<T extends ElementType = "div">(
  { as, children, ...props }: MyProps<T>,
  ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLElement>,
): ReactElement<T> {
  
  const Comp = as ?? "div";

  return (
    <Comp {...props} ref={ref}>
      {children}
    </Comp>
  );
}

const MyComponent = forwardRef(_MyComponent);
export default MyComponent;

How do I need to change the Typescript so that I can get type suggestions?

I got it working by adding type assertion to the forwardRef call:
export const MyComponent = forwardRef(_MyComponent) as <
  T extends ElementType = "div"
>(
  props: MyProps<T> & { ref?: React.Ref<Element> }
) => ReactElement | null;

Usage
<MyComponent 
  as="label" 
  htmlFor="caption" // this autocompletes 
  asdf="" // this gives error
>
  Test
</MyComponent>

const MyGrid = ({ rows }: { rows: number }) => (
  <div style={{ gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${rows}, 1fr)` }}></div>
);

<MyComponent as={MyGrid} rows={4}>Test</MyComponent>;

Edit
Modifying MyProps so it works for HTML elements
type MyProps<T extends ElementType> = {
  as?: T;
} & ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>;


It appears to work for MyGrid but not HTML elements like "label".

Please see updated answer @KernelJames
